# Eclipse nested project turns into folder; only on one machine

Tags: java, eclipse

My eclipse started to do weird things when I tried to set up my project on my notebook.
What happens is that a package that should be nested like lots others in the project suddenly turns into a folder instead.

I found possible reasons for this behaviour [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344777/nested-folders-in-eclipse-classpath).

A possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761779/eclipse-packge-turns-into-a-directory-breaks-my-whole-project).

However the first link probably isn't my problem, because the project with the same files and the same nesting works well on other machines. The recommended solution also doesn't work, when I try to change the src-folders in the build path it says: "Cannot nest 'MMF/src/mmf/mappings' inside 'MMF/src'. To enable the nesting exclude 'mmf/' from 'MMF/src'"

It isn't my project so I shouldn't change the whole project-architecture. Any suggestions what might help me?

Comment: The Build Path Source is probably the problem. Remove the 'src' directory from the Source first and then add the 'src/mmf/mappings' (and any others) to the Source. Removing 'src' first will stop the nesting error.

Comment: thank you @greg-449 that worked, haven't expected a solution that easy anymore :)
Now for interest, why does this help? What went wrong?

Comment: You can't have 'src' and something inside 'src' both set as source directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended by @greg-449:

> The Build Path Source is probably the problem. Remove the 'src' directory from the Source first and then add the 'src/mmf/mappings' (and any others) to the Source. Removing 'src' first will stop the nesting error.

right-click on the project, Properties -> Java Build Path, Sources
There 'Remove' all sources, then 'Add file..' the src folder

Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its the user account. try loading your project up on another user account on the same machine where the settings are the original